# How do I merge these into 1 function

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Trying to code clean; the goal is to create rounded .Net objects.
 I would prefer to have 1 call regardless of object type as I figure this will get out of hand quickly.

## region BuildOvals

```
    //object fails as parameter Width/Height unavailable - there is likely a good way to merge these three void function 1 call but I "can't be asked" - Remo 2019

    public void buildOval(int oWDelta, int oHDelta, PictureBox o)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, o.Width - oWDelta, o.Height - oHDelta);
        Region rg = new Region(gp);
        o.Region = rg;
    }
    public void buildOval(int oWDelta, int oHDelta)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, this.Width - oWDelta, this.Height - oHDelta);
        Region rg = new Region(gp);
        this.Region = rg;
    }
    public void buildOval(int oWDelta, int oHDelta, Button o)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, o.Width - oWDelta, o.Height - oHDelta);
        Region rg = new Region(gp);
        o.Region = rg;
    }
    #endregion
```

...

Comment: pass the height to the method instead of Button or PictureBox

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you are saying.   The issue seems to be that if I pass a generic object - it doesn't like to be identified and a base object has no width/height is the main issue I believe.  I have some learning to do about the base object.

Comment: What do you mean with "generic object"? What I understood is, that you want to make one method out of the three, don't you? To make this, remove the button and picture box parameter from the method and instead pass the height directly

Comment: `public void buildOval(int oWDelta, int oHDelta, Control o)`

Comment: @MichaelRandall: instead of the default on the parameter, the caller should pass `this`. `this` is just another thing that derives from `Control`.

Comment: @madreflection ahh yes, indeed

Comment: @Julida - yes but I have to be able to access the width and height of the object

Comment: @MichaelRandall it says cannot be inferred from the usage when trying control o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could the following. From your code, it looks like the parameter `o` is a Control.  For example

```
public void buildOval(int oWDelta, int oHDelta, Control o)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
    {
       gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, o.Width - oWDelta, o.Height - oHDelta);
       Region rg = new Region(gp);
       o.Region = rg;
    }
}
```

You could now call them the methods as

```
 buildOval(wDeltaValue,oDeltaValue,this); // when called for Form
 buildOval(wDeltaValue,oDeltaValue,pictureBoxInstance);
 buildOval(wDeltaValue,oDeltaValue,buttonInstance);
```

Comment: You don't even need it to be generic. Just accept `Control` (instead of `T`).

Comment: Giving it a shot now; if it works i can give you some royalties as due

Comment: One more thing: get rid of the default on `o`. Instead, the caller should pass `this`.

Comment: you know; this is rather brilliant but i am missing something myself; when I call to allow this (form object) I can't seem to formulate the right call for that;

Comment: Your code will throw a null reference exception if `o` is null.

Comment: I need one of the calls to be able to handle an Oval for this (form1) main form

Comment: Oh, and also - `GraphicsPath` is an `IDisposable`, you should wrap it in a `using` statement.

Comment: @ZoharPeled fixed. @McChickenNuggets, please check the updated version. You could use pass `this` when used for Form

Comment: @McChickenNuggets: the latest edit of this answer has finally shaved it down to the bare minimum. That's what I was talking about in my *first* comment.

Comment: but how do I call for main form (base, Form1) - i atried buildOval(90, 0, null) and it barks

Comment: the null i understood the error but not sure how I pass

Comment: @McChickenNuggets: it's the first of the three calls he gave you: `buildOval(wDeltaValue,oDeltaValue,this);` ... "`this`" is the form.

Comment: nevermind - let me figure out how to give you both credit; works as expected, don't pass null pass this

Comment: ok - i don't know why i can't figure out how to mark as answer; i guess the devs on this site beat my brain processor; anyway going to set it appropriate; this is my first post here